# Efficiently fetching records on multiple condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, aasm

Using `aasm` `statemachine` for model `Booking`.

The state machine have below states

```
 state :payment_authorized
 state :payment_captured
 state :payment_failed
 state :some_more_states
```

So to fetch bookings based on state I can call `booking.payment_authorized`. But what am looking for is I want all records with state `payment_authorized` and `payment_captured`.

This works  `booking.payment_authorized + booking.payment_captured` but this is doing 2 database calls. one for finding `authorized_state` and other for `captured_state`. How can I do this more efficiently(in one call)?

Thank you

Comment: wouldn't `booking.payment_authorised` change the state of booking to 'payment_authorized' rather than checking it? Do you mean, `booking.payment_authorized?`

Comment: Yes, typo is fixed.. It will change. But there is a scenario where I need to fetch all records satisfying those two states...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Booking.payment_authorized.or(Booking.payment_captured)` to get all records in a single query.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 2):

@Tom gave a pretty good solution for the problem. It utilizes `ActiveRelation`'s `OR` for logical union of two relations. Note that the solution is specific to Rails 5.

You can also do it via:

```
Booking.where(aasm_state: [:payment_authorized, :payment_captured])
```

`aasm` uses `aasm_state` column to contain the state, by default. It will make the `IN` query.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This method works and easy to chain using scopes.

Comment: @Abhilash: Rails scoping will work with `OR` as well, since resultant of ActiveRelation is a Relation which can be chained. The slight advantage is how SQL queries `IN`(sorts and binary search) over `OR`(goes for all row by row).

Comment: Never used scopes with OR before. Thank you for the info.